# MLE of (reciprocal) Exponential Distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

I have a question in my homework -
[image]

I worked out that the Likelihood is
$ \frac{1}{\theta^n} e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}\sum y_i}$

The log likelihood is
$-n\ln(\theta) - \frac{1}{\theta}\sum y_i$

Differentiating,
$\frac{-n}{\theta} + \frac{2}{\theta^2}\sum y_i$

equating to zero,
$\frac{n}{\theta} = \frac{2}{\theta^2} n\bar{y}$

Should I just be crossmultiplying and factorising it out to get
$\theta(\theta - 2\bar{y}) = 0$

$\theta = 2\bar{y}$

I know this isn't a standard exponential, but I'm not sure if I can just do that.

Next questions asks
[image]

How do I compute Bias and standard error? I'm not familiar with computing these with a non-standard equation like this. If you could answer the other questions that would be greatly appreciated but is not of utmost importance!

Comment: Your differentiation is not correct. Be cautious when differentiating $\frac{1}{\theta}$. It may help to note that $\frac{1}{\theta} = \theta^{-1}$

Comment: Bias is defined as $\text{Bias} (\hat \theta, \theta) = \mathbb{E} (\hat \theta) - \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you differentiation has an excess $2$, and your way of finding $\hat \theta_{ML}$ is correct. Bias of an estimator is defined $E[\hat\theta-\theta]=E[\hat \theta]-\theta$. After substitution of $\bar y$, you'll find that the calculation is straightforward. For the standard error, you need to calculate $\sigma_{\hat\theta}$, which is $\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(\hat\theta)}$. Again, substituting $\bar y$ will make the calculation straightforward.